# Display product attachment in prestashop

Tags: php, html, image, attachment, prestashop-1.6

In prestashop when I add a picture as an attachment to a product it saves file in `download/filename` but the problem is that the filename is without extension

eg. `b112ddf78daac05a027abd52e67e8d2d6e6dee0a`

How to display picture in html (`<img src="">`) if filename does not have an extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the `$attachments` array to display the image on the product page? Since the extension doesn't matter (the browser looks for the mime type, see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110384/can-i-use-images-without-extension-in-img)), you could do the following :

```
{foreach from=$attachments item=attachment name=attachments}
  <img src="{$link->getPageLink('attachment', true, NULL, "id_attachment={$attachment.id_attachment}")|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for extension. Just pass the variable to `src` and it's fine.