# Get image data-src with Beautiful Soup when there is no image extension

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all the image urls for all the books on this page `https://www.nb.co.za/en/books/0-6-years` with beautiful soup.

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

baseurl = "https://www.nb.co.za/"
productlinks = []

r = requests.get(f'https://www.nb.co.za/en/books/0-6-years')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
productlist = soup.find_all('div', class_="book-slider-frame")

def my_filter(tag):
    return (tag.name == 'a' and
        tag.parent.name == 'div' and
        'img-container' in tag.parent['class'])

for item in productlist:
    for link in item.find_all(my_filter, href=True):
        productlinks.append(baseurl + link['href'])

        cover = soup.find_all('div', class_="img-container")
        print(cover)
```

And this is my output:

```
<div class="img-container">
<a href="/en/view-book/?id=9780798182539">
<img class="lazy" data-src="/en/helper/ReadImage/25929" src="/Content/images/loading5.gif"/>
</a>
</div>
```

What I hope to get:

```
https://www.nb.co.za/en/helper/ReadImage/25929.jpg
```

My problem is:

1. How do I get the data-sourcre only?
2. How to I get the extension of the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1: How do I get the data-source only?

You can access the `data-src` by calling `element['data-src']`:

```
cover = baseurl+item.img['data-src'] if item.img['src'] != nocover else baseurl+nocover
```

> 2: How to I get the extension of the image?

You can access the extension of the file like diggusbickus mentioned (good approache), **but** this will not help you if you try to request the file like *https://www.nb.co.za/en/helper/ReadImage/25929.jpg* this will cause a **404 error**.

The image is dynamically loaded / served additional infos -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/5110673/14460824

#### Example

```
baseurl = "https://www.nb.co.za/"
nocover = '/Content/images/no-cover.jpg'
data = []

for item in soup.select('.book-slider-frame'):
    
    data.append({
        'link' : baseurl+item.a['href'],
        'cover' : baseurl+item.img['data-src'] if item.img['src'] != nocover else baseurl+nocover
    })
    
data
```

#### Output

```
[{'link': 'https://www.nb.co.za//en/view-book/?id=9780798182539',
  'cover': 'https://www.nb.co.za//en/helper/ReadImage/25929'},
 {'link': 'https://www.nb.co.za//en/view-book/?id=9780798182546',
  'cover': 'https://www.nb.co.za//en/helper/ReadImage/25931'},
 {'link': 'https://www.nb.co.za//en/view-book/?id=9780798182553',
  'cover': 'https://www.nb.co.za//en/helper/ReadImage/25925'},...]
```

Answer (score 1):

i'll show you how to do it for that small example, i'll let you handle the rest. just use the `imghdr` module

```
import imghdr

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data="""<div class="img-container">
<a href="/en/view-book/?id=9780798182539">
<img class="lazy" data-src="/en/helper/ReadImage/25929" src="/Content/images/loading5.gif"/>
</a>
</div>"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
base_url="https://www.nb.co.za"
img_src=soup.select_one('img')['data-src']
img_name=img_src.split('/')[-1]
data=requests.get(base_url+img_src)
with open(img_name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data.content)

print(imghdr.what(img_name))
>>> jpeg
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot and worked. The answer from above also worked, and in away suited my needs better.  Thank you for your input.

Answer (score -1):

To wait until all images are loaded you can tell `requests` to use [`timeout` argument](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts) or set it to `timeout=None` which will tell `requests` to wait forever for a response if the page loaded slowly.

The reason why you get a `.gif` at the end of the image results is that the image hasn't been loaded yet and a gif was showing that.

You can [access `data-src` attribute the same way you would access a dictionary](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes): `class[attribute]`

---

If you want to save an image locally, you can use [`urllib.request.urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve):

```py
import urllib.request

urllib.request.urlretrieve("BOOK_COVER_URL", file_name.jpg) # will save in the current directory
```

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Get-image-data-src-with-Beautiful-Soup):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

response = requests.get(f'https://www.nb.co.za/en/books/0-6-years', timeout=None)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

for result in soup.select(".img-container"):
    link = f'https://www.nb.co.za{result.select_one("a")["href"]}'

    # try/except to handle error when there's no image on the website (last 3 results)
    try:
        image = f'https://www.nb.co.za{result.select_one("a img")["data-src"]}'
    except: image = None

    print(link, image, sep="\n")


# part of the output:
'''
# first result (Step by Step: Counting to 50)
https://www.nb.co.za/en/view-book/?id=9780798182539
https://www.nb.co.za/en/helper/ReadImage/25929

# last result WITH image preview (Dinosourusse - Feite en geite: Daar’s ’n trikeratops op die trampoline)
https://www.nb.co.za/en/helper/ReadImage/10853
https://www.nb.co.za/en/view-book/?id=9780624035480

# last result (Uhambo lukamusa (isiZulu)) WITH NO image preview on the website as well so it returned None
https://www.nb.co.za/en/view-book/?id=9780624043003
None
'''
```