# How to see the actual image load error? (HTMLImageElement - onerror)

Tags: javascript, dom

In JavaScript is there a way to see actual error a given `HTMLImageElement` failed to load (no codec, corrupt, not found, etc...)?  Does `onerror` event handler have any arguments to help with this?

Comment: have you looked at [jQuery .error](http://api.jquery.com/error/)?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815762/detect-when-an-image-fails-to-load-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Good news, [it's totally possible.](http://jsbin.com/ivOVEDA/3/edit?html,css,js,output)

Unfortunately the error event doesn't bubble correctly.  You also will more than likely need to set the image's `src` in JS to ensure the events are bound before the error event can be thrown.

[Here's some reading on image loading errors not bubbling.](http://m.cg/post/30934181934/error-events-dont-bubble-from-images-and-how-to-work)