# Update img src if image does not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 possible images to show. If the first one exists, show it; if not, show the second one

This code will be shown in multiple pages so if the first image doesn't exist, it shows it src either as "undefined" or "unknown"
So I need to specify this 2 instances

I was trying the following, but as soon as I add the "or unknown" it breaks:

```html
<div id="section-heading">
  <div id="topBannerG" class="groupImageHidden">
    <img src="(unknnown)">
  </div>
  <div id="topBannerG" class="groupImageHidden">
    <img id="ctl00_ctl26_imgBanner" src="image.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imageDef = $("#topBannerG.groupImageHidden img");

  if (typeof imageDef == "undefined") || (typeof imageDef === "unknown") {
    var imgHref = $('.groupImage img').attr("src");
    $('#section-heading').prepend('<div id="topBannerG" class="mslwidget maxWidth groupImage"><img src="' + imgHref + '" style="border-width:0px;"></div> ');
  } else {
    var imgTopHref = $('#topBannerG img').attr("src");
    $('#section-heading').prepend('<div id="topBannerG" class="mslwidget maxWidth msl-pagebanner"><img id="ctl00_ctl26_imgBanner" src="' + imgTopHref + '" style="border-width:0px;"></div> ');
  }
});
```

Comment: If by "doesn't exist" you mean "fails to load", you need to add an event listener to determine if it loaded or not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815762/detect-when-an-image-fails-to-load-in-javascript

Comment: You can solve this with just CSS btw: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/wrn8jbof/

Comment: you can also use ng-if for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made this more complicated than it needs to be. The simplest way to achieve what you require is to add the `img` to the DOM with the original `src` URL. Then add an `error` handler in JS which is called if the image fails to load. At that point you can then update the `src` to an image which you know works. Something like this:

```js
$('#topBannerG img').on('error', function() {
  this.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/CbsGGVp.jpg';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="section-heading">
   <div id="topBannerG" class="groupImageHidden">
        <img src="invalid.jpg" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your code with same logic hope it will help!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //var imageDef = $("#topBannerG.groupImageHidden img");
  var imageDef1 = document.querySelectorAll("#topBannerG.groupImageHidden img")
  //console.log("imageDef--",imageDef1)
  imageDef1.forEach(function(imageDef) {
    console.log("imageDef-", imageDef.src)
    if (imageDef.src == "" || imageDef.src == '') {
      var imgHref = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRpFBWqwBWz1PssMHzubdkMu9dMhzd1HCScBqc0ReHNeCDvtYStWA';
      $('#section-heading').prepend('<div id="topBannerG" class="mslwidget maxWidth groupImage"><img src="' + imgHref + '" style="border-width:0px;"></div> ');
    } else {
      var imgTopHref = imageDef.src;
      $('#section-heading').prepend('<div id="topBannerG" class="mslwidget maxWidth msl-pagebanner"><img id="ctl00_ctl26_imgBanner" src="' + imgTopHref + '" style="border-width:0px;"></div> ');
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section-heading">
  <div id="topBannerG" class="groupImageHidden">
    <img src(unkown)>
  </div>

  <div id="topBannerG" class="groupImageHidden">
    <img id="ctl00_ctl26_imgBanner" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Logo_Google_2013_Official.svg/1280px-Logo_Google_2013_Official.svg.png">
  </div>

</div>
```