# Client-side Javascript: Create array of files in a directory

Tags: javascript, loops, file-traversal

I'm trying to make a For Loop in javascript that for every number added, will correspond to a file in a folder which will then be added to a list.  Is this possible? (code below, I'm sure that there are silly mistakes but that's not my concern at the moment)

```js
for(var i = 1; until file is not detected; i++){
     list = list + "fileNumber"+i+".png";
     return list
}
```

Alternatively, would something like this be better? (mild pseudocode warning):

```js
for (var i = 1; 1<2;i++){
     if "filenumber"+i+".png" does not exist:
          return list 
          break
     else:
          list = list +"filenumber"+i+".png"
}
```

When it's done, the list should look like this:

```js
list = [fileNumber1.png, fileNumber2.png, fileNumber3.png]
```

Is something like this possible? Am I SOL? if it isn't, are there any alternative ways I can do it without having to learn an entire new language???

For context, I'm trying to make a "previous" and "next" button in html. When pressed, the image on screen will change to either the previous image, or the next image depending on the button (like flipping a page in a book).  This wouldn't be too big of an issue, except that I have very little idea on how to get a list of the images I have without doing it manually (I want to have the potential of 50+ images, and don't want to change the list every time I add one)

Comment: So you want to add all the files in a directory to an array using javascript?

Comment: If you're running javascript in the browser, you have no read access to the filesystem so this will not be possible.  If you're running javascript in a Node server, `fs.readdirSync(path)` will get you started.

Comment: (I guess in theory in browser js you could try to load all the images in the background, and wait for one to time out as an indication that it doesn't exist... but it'd be a lot easier to just edit an images array length in your javascript when you add a new image file)

Comment: Since the file in question is an image, you could try to load the image using javascript and then detect if the load fails - then you know. This post should guide you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56166153/1772933

Comment: Your first loop is clearly wrong. It returns unconditionally on the first iteration, it will never fetch other images.

Comment: I'm not really sure why you think you need a loop at all. The next/previous button doesn't need to loop, it just loads one image. If it doesn't exist, it just leave the image the way it is.

Comment: @Barmar would you mind telling me how it should be then?  I know that the return list function ends the loop, but im not sure how I would get the completed list without it.

Comment: @Kinglish Looks promising!! I'll see if i can figure out how to implement it!

Comment: You don't need "the complete list". Just use a global variable with the current index. To go to the next image, you increment the variable and test if that image exists.

Comment: @Jacob Yes!! That's exactly what I'm trying to do, I just don't really know how to go about doing it

Comment: Where does this run. In the browser (which has no concept of a filesystem), in Node, in Bun, in Deno...? (i.e. remember to tag your post properly)

Answer (score -1):

If [directory indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932641/deny-directory-listing-with-htaccess) is enabled, you can create an array of the files in a specified directory using purely **client-side javascript** by fetching an HTML page (*generated by Apache's directory listing*) that lists the files in the directory, then parses the data to extract the file names. In the code I have provided below, I am doing an additional check to ensure it is either a jpg or png - you can adjust this as needed or remove it completely.

```
function loadDirectoryListing() {
    fetch('/path/to/directory/')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(html => {
            const parser = new DOMParser();
            const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
            const links = doc.querySelectorAll('a');

            const files = Array.from(links)
                .map(link => link.textContent)
                .filter(text => text.endsWith('.png') || text.endsWith('.jpg'));

            console.log(files);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error loading directory:', error));
}
window.onload = loadDirectoryListing;
```

**Note:** I do not recommend this method, as it is not completely reliable, and does pose some security concerns. Generally, directory indexing is frowned upon, and I would suggest using a server-side script to produce the array. However, since the question asks how to do it using client-side JavaScript, I have provided a solution using client-side JavaScript.

Comment: This is true, but that would in _most_ cases indicate a security hole that needs to be closed rather than a "feature" to use in production...