# Is there code that can be used to alert user when image does not load?

Tags: javascript, image, error-handling, onload, src

I have an image that I am loading from a server. I am doing this through the following code.

```
img.onload = function () {
   loadingStop = true;
   ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
   startDrawing();
}
img.src = imageLink;
```

When the image loads the program goes on its merry way. However, incase the photo will not load, I want to `alert(msg)` the user of the problem. How can I do this with JavaScript?

Comment: I personally do not know how to do this however hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815762/detect-when-an-image-fails-to-load-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)

```html
<img src="../missing-file.jpg" onerror="myAlertFunction()">
```

```js
function myAlertFunction() {
  alert('The image could not be loaded.');
}
```