# javascript/jquery check whether an image exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, url

Given an image url below
http://www.bikewalls.com/pictures/abc.jpg (does not load)

I need a javascript/jquery function/code to alert saying the above url is valid or not.These urls will be passed as parameters. Taking the case of above example will be very helpful.

Comment: And where did you get stuck writing this function?

Comment: In [this prior StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714525/javascript-image-url-verify/9714891#9714891) is a function called `testImage()` that takes an image URL to test and will call your callback and tell you if the image loaded successfully or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `onload` and `onerror` callback like this:

```
var img = new Image();
var url = "http://www.vbarter.com/images/content/3/2/32799.JPG";
img.onload = function(){
    alert("the image exists");
    // display image or whatever you need
};
img.onerror = function(){
    alert("error while loading..");  
    // handle the error
}

img.src = url;
```

**FIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/473GV/

Answer (score 0):

Quick and simple using jQuery:

```
$("<img/>")
    .load(function() {
        console.log("image loaded correctly");
    })
    .error(function() {
        alert("error loading image");
    })
    .attr("src", $(originalImage).attr("src"));
```

Obviously you would have to adapt this to your particular case, but you get the idea. You can read more about jQuery's `$.error()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/error/).