# Display image by url using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, backbone.js

I am developing my project using `backbone.js`, `underscore.js`, `require.js` and `text.js`.

I am required to display image that return from c# controller, in my underscore template file. So I did :

```
<img src=<%=URLBrand+brand[i].ID%> class="brandimg">
```

In my browser console I got :

```
<img class="brandimg" src="http://example.com/brand/21">
```

Error  : failed to load given url.

Note : `http://example.com/brand/21` is a controller of c# web service return string url of image.

How can I display image return from any url using javascript?

Any answer is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There's already an answer for this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714525/javascript-image-url-verify

Comment: The type that return from url is actually an image so I don't need to test it.

Answer (score 0):

As my thinking, you should get the String URL of image first, and then put it in your `<img src="put here"/>`. You can use ajax for doing this.

Comment: URL of each image is dynamic and load by underscore.js value and it is not able to write underscore value in javascript function. That's why I couldn't use ajax function here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the url string via AJAX-request. And then you can put returned string into src attribute of IMG tag

```
  Backbone.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/brand/21",
    success: function(returnedURL){
        //code here
    }
});
```

Comment: URL of each image is dynamic and load by `underscore.js` value and it is not able to write `underscore` value in javascript function. That's why I couldn't use ajax function here.