# Detect if given url is proper image in JS synchronously

Tags: javascript

I am trying to predetermine is a given url is a valid image or not.
In JS, it would be ideally look like

```
if (isValidImg(url)){
    ...add image DOM
} else { ... discard...}
```

Given img.src is happening asynchronously, how can I synchronously know if the url is a valid image?

Valid meaning exist, and has a image related format or mime type.

"http://google.com/fake.img" is not valid

"http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=a7723f5f7e59" is valid

Comment: *"how can I synchronously know if the url is a valid image"* You can't. You cannot eat the pizza before it was delivered.

Comment: You can make synchrous ajax request to server to `url` and there check if it is image or not and do other stuff synchronously, but be aware to no suspend your main thread

Comment: Please define "valid".

Comment: @Epsil0neR Except synchronous ajax [is in the process of being deprecated](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning), it's best avoided.

Comment: The browser is not built for synchronous network IO requests because they tend to lead to a bad user experience, so I'd suggest you spend more of your effort on reworking your approach and code so you can use an asynchronous request to validate an image URL.

Comment: When you decide to do this operation asynchronous, here is some code on validating an image asynchronously: [Javascript Image Url Verify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714525/javascript-image-url-verify/9714891#9714891)

Comment: I should actually add that while it's kind of annoying to formulate, it's a good idea to have whatever server request gave you the URL of the image also give you its width and height (especially if it was the initial HTML document request) to fill the `<img>` attributes. This causes the page layout to remain relatively constant as content is filled in.

Answer (score 0):

It would be completely crazy to do that synchronously, but you can do it asynchronously. In a modern browser, or using a Promise shim/library in any browser, you can do this:

```
function isValidImg( url ) {
    return new Promise( function ( resolve, reject ) {

        var image = new Image;

        image.onload = function ( ) { resolve( image ) };
        image.onerror = image.onabort = reject;

        image.src = url;
    } );
}
```

Adapted from [jfriend00's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9714891/772035), which will work in any browser without needing a Promise library. Then use it like this:

```
isValidImg( url ).then( function ( image ) {
    // Add image to DOM
}, function ( event ) { 
    // Handle error
    // Note: This will be reached when the image fails to load
    //       whether that be because it's not a valid image or 
    //       any other reason.
} );
```

Comment: I'd revise the second example to: `isValidImg( url ).then( function ( image ) {/*add image*/}, function() { /*report to user or page that image is invalid*/ } );` since the second case is the one the OP expressed interest in.

Comment: @Katana314 Good point. I took `** discard **` to mean do nothing, but it would at least be good to show where they would handle the error.

Comment: @Katana314 I took your suggestion into account and updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

As the comments on your question indicate, you should try to use async requests over sync requests wherever and whenever possible.

You should send a HEAD request to the url and check the `Content-Type` header is a valid image type.

**Asynchronous**

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('HEAD', url);
request.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
    {
        var contentType = request.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
        if (contentType.slice(0,6) === 'image/')
            // URL is valid image
    }
};
request.send();
```

**Synchronous** (Don't do this!)

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('HEAD', url, false);
request.send();
if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
{
    var contentType = request.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
    if (contentType.slice(0,6) === 'image/')
        // URL is valid image
}
```