# How to let users copy and paste an image into a div?

Tags: javascript, image, url

I have a system where my users can edit a div and save what they typed into it. I want them to be able to paste an image into the div through a URL, how can I do that? (Please note that I can't use PHP since I'm hosting it off of GitHub :3 )

Comment: Maybe this answer will be of some use [**javascript image url verify**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714525/javascript-image-url-verify#answer-9714891)