# hide broken img chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome-extension

**my issue:** On jsfiddle, I managed to successfully hide broken image icon. However when loaded up on Chrome extension, It doesn't work :/

example: [image: https://imgur.com/a/T6wdnD2]

**some background:** the "post.url" may or may not be an image file. And I would like to hide it if it's not. How do I do that?

**This is my current code:**

```
$("#art").append('<img id="img" src="' + post.url + '"onerror="this.style.display=\'none\'"/>');
```

Comment: maybe you are looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714525/javascript-image-url-verify#answer-9714891, then if its not valid url then you can hide it

Comment: yeah i have seen that post. but i don't wanna use it because of "function checkURL(url) {
    return(url.match(/\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$/) != null);
}" because many url contains gifv that would show broken image too. but gif is fine. so i'm thinking that the match will return gifv too

Comment: @KwokWenJian No, the regex only matches extensions.

Comment: @MrLister you're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. use the correct devtools - extension popup has its own separate one accessible by right-clicking the popup, then clicking "inspect" (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920982) for various browsers);
2. in the correct devtools you'll see the error about inline JS being blocked;
3. since [extensions can't use inline JS by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721457) (this is a good thing so don't change it),
   instead attach the onerror listener programmatically:

```
$(`<img id="img" src="${post.url}">`).appendTo('#art').on('error', function() {
  this.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Comment: i don't know why, but when i used your code, and when it is error, it doesn't run the lines of code after that

Comment: @KwokWenJian, thanks for the heads up, I've reworked the code.

Comment: works perfectly now :) May i trouble you to check this code too? i am also trying to fetch video link. there are two keys (either one or the other) to retrieve the link. so i do this: try {
       $("#art").append('<video id="img" controls autoplay loop><source src="' + post.preview.reddit_video_preview.fallback_url + '"></video>');
      } catch(err) {
       $("#art").append('<video id="img" controls autoplay loop><source src="' + post.media.reddit_video.fallback_url + '"></video>');
      } it works, but should i be doing this? is there a better way?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe? Looks like a different issue for a separate question I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to check as Rahul and Mr lister has suggested

```
function checkURL(url) {
    return(url.match(/\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$/) != null);
}
```