# How to get Extension of image in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

Here I check image Extension using below code. `imageName.split(".").pop()` using `split and pop` I got image extension, but after this I have to check this extension is matched with this for that I have to check with multiple or condition so it is make process of code is slow so Is there any possiblity to make code reduced and reduce OR condtions.

Ex. If jpEg extension image that time only with one condition `(extn == jpeg)` is check all type small,capital extension
`('jpeg','Jpeg','jPeg','jpEg','jpeG','JPeg','JpEg','JpeG','jPEg','jPeG','jpEG','jPEG','JPeG','JPEg','JpEG','JPEG')` and make less or conditions

```
previewFiles(imageName){
 console.log(imagename);  // 125.jpEg

 var extn = imageName.split(".").pop();

   console.log(extn);  // jpEg

  if((extn == 'pdf') || (extn == 'PDF') || (extn == 'pdF') || (extn == 'pDf') ||
     (extn == 'pDF') || (extn == 'PDf') || (extn == 'PdF') || (extn == 'Pdf') ||
     (extn == 'jpg') || (extn == 'JPG') || (extn == 'jpG') || (extn == 'jPg') ||
     (extn == 'jPG') || (extn == 'JPg') || (extn == 'JpG') || (extn == 'Jpg') ||
     (extn == 'gif') || (extn == 'GIF') || (extn == 'giF') || (extn == 'gIf') ||
     (extn == 'gIF') || (extn == 'GIf') || (extn == 'GiF') || (extn == 'Gif') ||
     (extn == 'png') || (extn == 'PNG') || (extn == 'pnG') || (extn == 'pNg') ||
     (extn == 'pNG') || (extn == 'PNg') || (extn == 'PnG') || (extn == 'Png') ||
     (extn == 'tif') || (extn == 'TIF') || (extn == 'tiF') || (extn == 'tIf') ||
     (extn == 'tIF') || (extn == 'TIf') || (extn == 'TiF') || (extn == 'Tif') ||
     (extn == 'jpeg') || (extn == 'Jpeg') || (extn == 'jPeg') || (extn == 'jpEg') ||
     (extn == 'jpeG') || (extn == 'JPeg') || (extn == 'JpEg') || (extn == 'JpeG') ||
     (extn == 'jPEg') || (extn == 'jPeG' ) || (extn == 'jpEG' ) || (extn == 'jPEG' ) ||
     (extn == 'JPeG' ) || (extn == 'JPEg') || (extn == 'JpEG') || (extn == 'JPEG') ||
     (extn == 'tiff') || (extn == 'Tiff' ) || (extn == 'tIff') || (extn == 'tiFf' ) ||
    (extn == 'tifF') || (extn == 'TIff') || (extn == 'TiFf') || (extn == 'TifF') ||
     (extn == 'tIFf') || (extn == 'tIfF') || (extn == 'tiFF') || (extn == 'tIFF') ||
     (extn == 'TIfF') || (extn == 'TIFf') || (extn == 'TiFF') || (extn == 'TIFF')){
      console.log("extension of image is matched");    
   }else{
      console.log("extension of image is not matched");
   }
}
```

Comment: please use `toLowerCase()` to convert any extension.
then all extensions will be changed to lowercase string.
And you will check easily

Comment: PDFs are not images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Image Url Verify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714525/javascript-image-url-verify)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use a regex using an alternation and the `/i` for a case insensitive comparison or string compare using [toLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase):

```js
let extn = "TIFf";
const regex = /(?:pdf|jpeg|jpg|tiff?|gif|png)/i;
if (regex.test(extn)) {
  console.log(extn);
}

let valid = [
  "pdf", "tif", "tiff", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png"
];

if (valid.includes(extn.toLowerCase())) {
  console.log(extn);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could simply call `extn.toLowerCase()` on a string having every `JpEg`, `jpEg` in lowercase `jpeg` representation.

What you could do also is having available extensions in another variable and check given extension if it match with any from the array

```
const availableExtensions = new Set(['jpeg', 'tiff', 'gif'])

if(availableExtensions.has(extn.toLowerCase())) {
    console.log("extension of image is matched")
}
```